# Adding OpenGL imports automatically with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

I am new with OpenGL. I have just installed LWJGL and created a User Library in Eclipse. It is linked to my Project but what Eclipse won't do is to import the needed classes automatically. Is there a way to get it work? I don't like to write (e.g.) `GL30.glMethodName()` every time and I also don't like to make a static import like `import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*` (which is bad practice).

Comment: You may want to take a look to jogl, where you have to write `gl.glMehodName()`

Comment: I did this, but I am a student and my prof doesn't want us to use this. :(

Comment: I don't think you have other choices than the ones you mentioned then

Comment: Your prof wants you to add them by hand, and not using a tool. It will be good, so you could grow in expertize, knowing what to add, when to add, and being able to clean eventual unnecessary included packages - usually programmers that use auto-add imports don't care cleaning their input package list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the preferences window with `Window -> Preferences`.
2. Go to `Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favorites`.
3. Click `New Type...`.
4. Enter `org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11`.
5. Do steps 3 and 4 for each GL** class.
6. When you now enter something like `glGenVertexArrays();` and hover your mouse over it, there is an option `Add static import for 'GL30.glGenVertexArrays'`. Select it to add the import.
7. Additionally, you can now type something like `glGenVertex` and press `Ctrl+Space` to get a popup menu of available methods. Selecting one of them automatically adds the import.